# Do RNA molecules bind each other?

Tags: molecular-biology, rna

I have a question, maybe a naive one.

Let's assume that we isolated some RNA from a tissue. Do RNA molecules can bind each other if they have the complementary sequence? I know that some small RNA molecules can bind other RNAs and regulate them but I do not know it is possible in this case? It is like 2 different mRNA can bind each other or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between RNA and DNA is rather small, and both can form a double-helix structure. So if you had two sequences of RNA complementary to each other they would basepair and form a helix.

There were also some ideas to use this for therapeutic purposes, [antisense RNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisense_RNA), an RNA oligo complementary to a messenger RNA, can theoretically be used to silence gene expression by base-pairing to the mRNA.

Comment: Thanks. But do they need to be completely complementary or not? And during the experiments, is there a way to prevent this issue?

Comment: @golgicik Not completely, a certain amount of mismatches would be tolerated. There are various programs to calculate the likely secondary structure of RNA like MFold or the Vienna RNA package you could use to predict the structure of your specific RNA.

Comment: Thanks @Mad Scientist. I think 2-ME would prevent it, right?

Comment: @golgicik 2'-OMe doesn't really affect base-pairing, it's a modification of the ribose.

Comment: I mean 2-Mercaptoethanol.

Comment: Would ME prevent secondary structure? I think at reasonable concentrations it would have little effect and it's not used (as far as I know) as a denaturant.

Comment: @golgicik 2-ME doesn't denature secondary structures. It is a reducing agent that reduces disulphide bonds in proteins. **Urea** will denature RNAs just like it does  proteins.

Comment: @golgicik for hybridizing two RNA strands you can use UNAfold. However, it doesn't compute it for RNAs longer than 500nt. Also, in RNA **G** can form a wobble base pair with **U**

Answer (score 3):

@MadScientist answer is very good. I just want to add a detail that could not fit in a comment.

Double stranded RNA is nothing exceptional. You can see an RNA strand that binds to its antisense in [tRNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_RNA) and in [RNAi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA_interference) for example.

**tRNA**

[image]

**RNAi**

[image]